# Наследование методов Java

Tags: java, наследование

Есть класс **Warship**, в котором есть метод, ну например ***turnLeft()***.
Я создаю класс **Destroyer**, который наследует от **Warship**, потом класс **GroznyyKlass**, который наследует от **Destroyer** и, наконец создаю экземпляр класса **GroznyyKlass**, который называется **Gromkiy**.

Вопрос:

Метод ***Gromkiy.turnLeft()*** выполнится при вызове?

Это нормально такое множественное последовательное наследование?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Да. Тоже, да.**

А зачем блокнот, почему не IDE?.

Comment: Спасибо! :)    Блокнот физический, бумажный, я в нём задумки и схемы пишу( думаю так) . А дома всё есть и Notepad ++ и Eclipse и Intelij Idea.